# remove header MQIIH from message

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a MQIIH structure that is sent through a queue manager and the receiving side (out of my control)  is  having problem s with receiving it after a change.

`MQIIH  IMS information header` (as per [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1001_xiao/1001_xiao.html))

Is there a way to remove the header in MQ, without using a program IIB?

Answer (score 1):

> is having problems with receiving it after a change.

After what change?  If you change the MQIIH and it does NOT match the MQIIH structure then of course the receiving end will have a problem.  Have you verified that the MQIIH structure that you are sending to the other end is correct?

Note: The MQIIH structure has not changed in more than 10 years.  I'm using MQ v8 and MQIIH structure is exactly the same.